# Can Jupyter Console be used with Google Cloud Datalab?

Tags: jupyter, google-cloud-datalab, jupyter-console

Can [Jupyter Console](http://jupyter-console.readthedocs.io/) be used with Google Cloud Datalab as a replacement for the javascript frontend?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to me that one could use the Google Cloud Shell for the functionality you may be looking for? Located on the upper right of the Google Cloud Platform control page?

Comment: I'm not sure. The idea with Jupyter Console is to have a lighter/elegant-er interface to Jupyter Notebooks.

Comment: I agree it would be nice to have it available that way , via the Jupyter console, but at the moment the Google Cloud console is a reasonable working solution IMHO..

Comment: I realised Jupyter Console is a frontend for a given kernel, so little more than a repl. I thought it was a frontend for Jupyter Notebooks, so this question is misguided.

Answer (score 1):

It will be possible very soon to use Datalab with the Jupyter notebook. We have no plans to support Jupyter Console directly, but parts of Datalab should work.